# React JS React-router-dom6 doesn't navigate to the page by useNavigate

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, antd, redux-toolkit

I'm using react-router-dom6 & redux-toolkit & antd form
and I'm saving the token to localstorage. what I want is that after logging in, redirecting to dashboard page but instead it redirects to empty page with the same url of dashboard & when I reload the dashboard page contents displayed

routes.tsx

```
{!token ? (
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/login" />} />
    <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
    <Route path="/signUp" element={<SignUp />} />
    <Route path="/resetPassword" element={<ResetPassword />} />
  </Routes>
) : (
  <>
    <Sidebar collapsed={collapsed} />
    <Layout className="site-layout">
      <Header collapsed={collapsed} collapseHandler={collapseHander} />
      <div className="contentContainer">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/dashboard" />} />
          <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
          {role === "1" && <Route path="/groupList" element={<GroupList />} />}
          <Route path="/newOrder" element={<NewOrder />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
      <Footer>footer</Footer>
    </Layout>
  </>
)}
```

loginSlice.ts

```
export const postLogIn = createAsyncThunk(
  "login/postLogIn",
  ({ email, password }: Login, { dispatch }) => {
    return axios
      .post("/login", {
        email,
        password
      })
      .then((response) => {
        successMessage(response.data.status);
        if (response.status === 200) {
          console.log(response.data.data, "login");
          localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.data.Token);
          localStorage.setItem("role", response.data.data.role);
          localStorage.setItem("user_id", response.data.data.user_id);
          localStorage.setItem("user_name", response.data.data.full_name);
          localStorage.setItem("email", response.data.data.email);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        errorMessage(err.message);
      });
  }
);
const logInSlice = createSlice({
  name: "login",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(postLogIn.pending, (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
      state.error = false;
    });
    builder.addCase(postLogIn.fulfilled, (state) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = false;
    });
    builder.addCase(postLogIn.rejected, (state) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = true;
    });
  }
});

export default logInSlice.reducer;
```

loginForm.tsx

```
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const onFinish = (values: any) => {
    dispatch(postLogIn(values));
    if (!error) {
      navigate("/dashboard", { replace: true });
    }
  };

              <Form
                className="form"
                name="login-form"
                wrapperCol={{
                  span: 24
                }}
                initialValues={{
                  remember: true
                }}
                onFinish={onFinish}
                autoComplete="off">
---
</Form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You missed sharing a complete code example, i.e. where `token` is declared/set/read in the `routes.tsx` file, but I don't think that is the cause of the issue. The issue is that `postLogIn` is an asynchronous action and the `onFinish` callback doesn't wait for it to complete, i.e. resolve, prior to redirecting to `"/dashboard"`. The reason the URL changes to `"/dashboard"` and nothing is rendered is because there is no `!token` route matching `"/dashboard"` and no general fallback to redirect to a known handled path. I'd be willing to bet there's a RRD warning in the console about no matching route found for path `"/dashboard"`.

```
{!token ? (
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/login" />} />
    <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
    <Route path="/signUp" element={<SignUp />} />
    <Route path="/resetPassword" element={<ResetPassword />} />
    // <-- no matched route for "/dashboard", render nothing
  </Routes>
) : (
  ...
)}
```

## Solution

`dispatch(postLogIn(values));` returns a Promise object so the `onFinish` should wait for Promise to resolve.

Example:

```
const onFinish = async (values: any) => {
  try {
    await dispatch(postLogIn(values));
    navigate("/dashboard", { replace: true });
  } catch (error) {
    // catch and handle any rejected Promises or thrown errors
  }
};
```

### Suggestion

When you conditionally render the routes there's potential for navigating/redirecting to a conditionally rendered route ***prior*** to the condition changing and the route not actually being rendered just yet. Your code might work more smoothly if you implemented *actual* route protection and unconditionally render all the routes.  Here's an simple example:

```
import { Navigate, Outlet, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
const ProtectedRoute = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const token = /* wherever the token value is coming from */

  return token
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/login" replace state={{ from: location }} />;
};
```

...

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/login" />} />
  <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
  <Route path="/signUp" element={<SignUp />} />
  <Route path="/resetPassword" element={<ResetPassword />} />
  <Route element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
    <Route element={<LayoutWithSidebarLayoutHeaderFooter />}>
      <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
      {role === "1" && <Route path="/groupList" element={<GroupList />} />}
      <Route path="/newOrder" element={<NewOrder />} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try again with: `<Navigate to="/dashboard" replace={true} />`

Comment: I've tried this. and after Signing in, it stays on the login page with no redirectng at all

Comment: @mera According to the docs you did the right thing, I'm wondering if you already have a `BrowserRouter` or not?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).